# (Mac) Realm Object Server Login Failed: Email/Password Incorrect

Tags: authentication, realm, realm-mobile-platform, realm-object-server

I installed Realm on computer1 and ran the Realm Object Server (creating a new admin user) then installed and ran Realm Object Server on computer2 attempting to create the same admin user I created on computer1. It immediately went to the login page where I assumed it had recognized my credentials from computer1 so I then filled in the same credentials and tapped Login. For some reason this alert is now showing on the screen:

> Login Failed: Email/Password combination incorrect.

In the server logs it states:

```
warn: auth.password: Handle request failed with: InvalidCredentials: The provided credentials are invalid.: Given account: foo@bar.com
```

I then restarted the Realm Server and attempted to create a different admin user with different credentials, after filling in the credentials and tap "submit" I am immediately taken to the login page where it gives the alert now saying:

> An error occured while setting up your account.

What is also interesting, is that after trying to create that new account I don't receive any information in the logs after tapping submit.

Comment: I was able to reproduce this issue using mixed case in the username e.g. `myEmail@gmail.com`. Changing this to `myemail@gmail.com` resolved the issue.

Answer (score 0):

It's not possible to run two copies of the Realm Object Server on multiple computers and share user accounts between them at the moment. Those will be two wholly separate and independent copies of the Realm Object Server.

Unless you registered two separate copies of the same admin account, the second login attempt will fail because the account doesn't exist in that instance.

We're working on adding additional scaling capabilities to the Realm Mobile Platform. Thanks for [filing an issue](https://github.com/realm/realm-mobile-platform/issues/75) on the Mobile Platform GitHub; we'll take it into consideration.

Comment: "Unless you registered two separate copies of the same admin account, the second login attempt will fail because the account doesn't exist in that instance." That is what is interesting. When I try and register a separate copy (on a separate computer) it says that there is an error on the webpage, but I don't see any errors in the logs. Are these logins being stored on another server?

Comment: Logins are stored in a special Realm file called `__admin.realm`, of which both copies of the Object Server should be controlling their own instances. I'm still trying to work out how this is actually set up. Have you got any apps trying to connect to both servers or anything like that?

Comment: Nope. I've completely shut down both instances but upon trying to create a new user in a newly run instance (fresh install) it errors...